# Tengo una propiedad en una clase, el cual contiene una lista de objetos de otra clase, ¿En que capa relleno la lista?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc, razor

Saludos,
Tengo una clase llamada Cv(Currículum vitae) y a parte de los propiedades típicas: Nombre, Apellido, DNI... tambien contiene una propiedad "Carnets de conducir" el cual es una lista de objetos de la clase "Carnets de conducir". ¿Dónde tengo que generar la lista y llenarla? Tenia pensado dentro de la propia vista Razor (con tipado fuerte), pues al final es para generar unos checboxs con cada uno de los carnets.
CÓDIGO:

Clase clsCV:

```
    [Display(Name = "NIF")]
    [Required]       
    public string NIF { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nom")]       
    public string Nom { get; set; }

    public List<clsCarnets> LlistaCarnets; //Lista de carnets la cual tiene un método preparado que me genera la lista y me la devuelve

    //Resto de propiedades
```

Controlador:

```
    public class CVController : Controller
{      
    // GET: CV
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CV()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Vista(dónde recive el tipado fuerte de la clase clsCV(currívulum vitae):

```
@model CurriculumVitaeMVC.Models.clsCv
@{
   Layout = null;
}
// Aquí formulario muy extenso con tipado fuerte --> Textboxfor, textareafor, etc... etc...
```

Comment: Creo que estas confundiendo atributos con propiedades, son cosas diferentes

Comment: A mi me han enseñado siempre mezclando las 2 palabras, pero oks. Ya lo he cambiado.

Comment: La liste debe estar en el modelo, y la debes llenar en el controller

Comment: Agrega codigo de lo que has intentado por favor

Comment: Lo ideal es que el `controller` se encargue de obtener los datos de alguna manera y que a la vista solo llegue lo que tiene que mostrar, en este caso una lista. La vista nunca debería encargarse de obtener datos, solo de mostrarlos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui te escribo este ejemplo simple el cual puedes ejecutar aqui:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/VUxjYp

**MODELO**

Los objetos y listas deben estar declarados en el modelo, a veces el modelo es una entidad de entity framework o un DTO, ejemplo:

```
namespace Ejemplo
{
   public class CV
    {
      public string Nombre{get;set;}
      public List<CarnetDeConducir> CarnetsDeConducir{get;set;}
    }

  public class CarnetDeConducir
    {
      public int Id{get;set;}
      public bool Vigente{get;set;}
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

Creas intancias de los objetos y llenas las listas en el controller:

```
namespace Ejemplo
{
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CV cv=new CV()
        {
            Nombre="Xavier",
            CarnetsDeConducir=new List<CarnetDeConducir>()
            {
                new CarnetDeConducir(){Id=1,Vigente=true},
                new CarnetDeConducir(){Id=2,Vigente=false},
            }
        };
        return View(cv);
    }

  }
}
```

**VIEW**

Y usas el View para ligarte a las propiedadeas del modelo (usando Strongly Typed modelo):

```
@using Ejemplo
@model Ejemplo.CV
@{
 Layout = null;
 }

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">


        table, th, td {
                       border: 1px solid black;
                      }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <span>Nombre</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Nombre)
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr><th>Id</th><th>Vigente</th></tr>
                @{int i=0;
                foreach(CarnetDeConducir cdc in Model.CarnetsDeConducir)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td><span>@cdc.Id</span></td>
                        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>@Model.CarnetsDeConducir[i].Vigente)</td>

                    </tr>
                    i++;
                }
                }
            </table>


        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

En cuanto a la sintaxis que use para mostrar los checkboxes, me base de aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25340436/3596441

(Perdon por el Spanglish)

Answer (score 1):

Los datos que usea la view debes generarlos desde el `action` en el `controller`

```
public class HomeController : Controller{

    public ActionResult Index(){

       var model = new CvViewModel(){
            Nombre = ..
            CarnetConducir = new List<CarnetConducir>()
        }
    }

    return View(model);

}
```

Como veras es desde el `action` se generan el model con los datos que la `view` requiere.

En el ejemplo define el model de forma simple, por supuesto en tu caso tomarias los datos de algun repositorio.